# SharePoint Designer Crash when opening a CSS file of 7k lines of code

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

My colleague's SharePoint Designer 2010 keeps crashing whenever he tries to open a stylesheet file that has more than 7,000 lines of code..

note that in my machine I can open files that has even more than 10,000 lines..

take in mind that we did the following..

1. Cleared the SPD cache according to the following links [1](https://web.archive.org/web/20200129164736/http://www.myspblog.com:80/2011/07/clear-sharepoint-designer-cache.html), [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20150930111242/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/03/27/tip-clearing-the-spd-workflow-assembly-cache.aspx)
2. Running the installation file again in repair mode
3. Uninstalled, and re-installed the SPD

running environment
Windows Server 2008 R2

but nothing seem to be working so far...
any suggestions please ?

Comment: Is the SPD located on the environment or his local computer?

Comment: SPD and the environment are on the same computer (his local computer)

Answer (score 0):

Try the 64-bit version of SharePoint Designer.

Comment: we couldn't install the 64-bit version, because the installed office on the machine is a 32-bit

Comment: For testing, I would try uninstalling all of Office so that you can try the 64-bit version.  If it works for you, then install the 64-bit version of Office (for 2010 it is on the same disk and will automatically use that version if SPD 64-bit is installed).